# Update bitmap in picturebox with data from a socket

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, image

I'm working on a screen sharing project, and I receive a small block of images from a `Socket` constantly. I need to update them on a certain initial desktop bitmap I have.

After receiving every block, it copies its pixels according to a specific position (`X` and `Y` parameters), which is how the initial image gets updated. But then comes the part where I need to display it on a `Picturebox`. I handle the `Paint` event and redrawing it all again. The entire initial image is pretty big (1920X1080 in my case).

```
private void MainScreenThread()
{
    ReadData();//reading data from socket.
    initial = bufferToJpeg();//first intial full screen image.
    pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;//activating the paint event.
    while (true)
    {
        int pos = ReadData();
        x = BlockX();//where to draw :X
        y = BlockY();//where to draw :Y
        Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg();//constantly reciving blocks.
        Draw(block, new Point(x, y));//applying the changes-drawing the block on the big initial image.

        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();//updaing the picturebox for seeing results.
            // this.Text = ((pos / 1000).ToString() + "KB");
        }));
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    lock (initial)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle); //draws at picturebox's bounds
    }
}
```

Because I'm aiming at high speed performance (it's kind of a real-time project), I would like to know if there's any method to draw the block itself on the picturebox instead of drawing the whole `initial` bitmap again. Plus, scaling it to the `Picuturebox` bounds  seems too inefficient to me.

The `picturebox` itself is not resizeable - it has a fixed width and height. But I need to scale the initial `Bitmap` every time (after processing the blocks) so it will fit the picturbox bounds to allow the client to see the full image. Despite their screen resolution, it's lower than the shared screen resolution (the server screen which is getting captured and shared).

This is my drawing method (works extremely fast, copying block with `memcpy`):

```
private unsafe void Draw(Bitmap bmp2, Point point)
{
    lock (initial)
    {  
        BitmapData bmData = initial.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, initial.Width, initial.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, initial.PixelFormat);
        BitmapData bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;
        int Width = bmp2.Width;
        int Height = bmp2.Height;
        int X = point.X;
        int Y = point.Y;

        scan0 = IntPtr.Add(scan0, stride * Y + X * 3);//setting the pointer to the requested line
        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            memcpy(scan0, scan02 ,(UIntPtr)(Width * 3));//copy one line

            scan02 = IntPtr.Add(scan02, stride2);//advance pointers
            scan0 = IntPtr.Add(scan0, stride);//advance pointers//
        }


        initial.UnlockBits(bmData);
        bmp2.UnlockBits(bmData2);
    }
```

Comment: If you're looking for more speed you might be able to get it by using hardware rendering and using a DirectX surface instead of a picturebox. I'm not an expert on this, but maybe something like SharpDX could help? http://sharpdx.org/wiki/usage/

Comment: @jrh I've never worked before with sharpdx, so I extremely confused about it.. what's actually the meaning of "create surface"? is there any way to draw on picture box with sharpdx or something?  I just don't understand where the sharpdx part comes in :(

Comment: I'll do some research and get back to you; in the meantime this question might help a little http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391911/c-sharp-winforms-anyone-know-of-a-c-sharp-gdi-library-not-slow-gdi ; I've seen hardware rendering used for a large performance benefit for high speed image processing but that was an unmanaged program, I have to look at how to best integrate it into Winforms.

Comment: @jrh awesome! I'll have a look on  this question. It's alright to use unmanaged code in c# i mean im fine with that- i uses unsafe pointers for fasrer bitmap access but i realised there are faster methods:). I really appreciate your effort! Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I found another couple of questions that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063178/net-redraw-at-60-fps , http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67651/what-is-the-standard-c-windows-forms-game-loop . I looked for a GPU accelerated API that integrated really easily into Winforms but unfortunately I wasn't able to find one. (I'm also bumping up against the limits of the Window-Invalidate-Redraw loop in the message pump)

Comment: @jrh hey,thanks for remembering this question! :)
i haven't actually find somthing good enough..

Comment: @jrh maybe once i'll move to cpp i would be able to integrate directx or opengl for faster operations.. :(

Comment: It seems like it shouldn't be necessary to use C++, but IMO the DirectX / OpenGL APIs are easier to use in C/C++ for some reason. [The Microsoft DirectX .NET APIs have been "rebooted" several times.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543653/directx-from-c-sharp). I know of a few solutions for hardware accelerated graphics but I don't know how to integrate them into a window with other controls (i.e., buttons, etc.), I've only used them for games where the full screen was a drawing canvas.

Comment: @jrh i understand...actualy i dont need hard 3d shapes drawing..simple 2d bitmap(or group of pixels.)..
i hope i'l find somthing later :)

Comment: Even for 2d graphics DirectX can help you. I looked into Direct2d -- as weird as it sounds, [there's some articles suggesting that Direct3d is actually easier to use for 2d graphics than Direct2d](http://braid-game.com/news/2009/01/a-demonstration-that-direct2d-is-patently-ridiculous/) and from the sample code I've looked at I agree... I've heard that WPF may have better hardware rendering support but I've never worked with WPF personally. Look for something with a capped frame rate that doesn't depend on controls notifying the OS when they need to be drawn. I think that might be my bottleneck

Answer (score 3):

If your blocks don't change size, why not create adjacent picture boxes so that you update each one individually?

If that isn't providing enough performance, remove the picture box altogether and create a custom user control where you override the `OnPaint` method and do your drawing inside of it.

This way, the you will pass your user control an array of bitmaps to draw and where to draw them and, when `OnPaint` gets called, you simply use [DrawImage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1(v=vs.110).aspx) to place each one at the appropriate location.

No need for you to join the bitmaps manually.

Should a new a image arrive and you want to force redrawing, simply call `Invalidate()` on the user control which will force `OnPaint` to be called. 
This can be optimized even further as `Invalidate` can be called only on a specific region of your control, allowing you to only redraw the parts that are necessary.

Comment: the blocks size are dynamic-everytime it comes with a different with and height(also different position of where to draw). about the custom control...i've never dont that before so i guess i'll need a little help :) but before doing that, i would like to show you the drawing method i use(to "merge" and draw the block on the initial image),it's extremly fast using the `memcpy` for copying memory. see my edited question. rembmer it should be as efficient and fast as possible,i spent alot of time for time measurement so my brain is quite dead now. look my post :)

Comment: I've update my answer accordingly. It's easier than you think, no need to manually merge bitmaps.

Comment: if i just had an example of how to do this ..haha.. would you like to write the steps for me for achieving  what you've pointed to?

Comment: dont forget it should be scaled at the end of the process :)

Comment: would you to expand your explaination a little bit?i've also tried to create a control with not much success...trying to override the `OnPaint` but actually overriding is done with the same arguments..and here i'm adding the bitmap block to draw on...hope you can help :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9CJmKLiU  @D. Jurcau